# Correctness of calculations with struct timespec

Tags: c, datetime, linux

I've noticed some discrepancies in timings in our system, and I'm trying to narrow down what could be causing them.

I'm reviewing out time abstraction, and as far as I can determine it's fine.

Am I missing anything, and is it portable (besides being constrained to POSIX)?

```
typedef struct timespec Time;
static inline Time getTime() {
    static struct timespec time;
    clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &time);
    return time;
}
static inline __constant Time timeAdd(Time oldTime, Time time) {
    if (time.tv_nsec + oldTime.tv_nsec >= 1E9)
        return (Time){
            tv_sec: time.tv_sec + oldTime.tv_sec + 1,
            tv_nsec: time.tv_nsec + oldTime.tv_nsec - 1E9
        };
    else
        return (Time){
            tv_sec: time.tv_sec + oldTime.tv_sec,
            tv_nsec: time.tv_nsec + oldTime.tv_nsec
        };
}
static inline __constant Time timeDiff(Time oldTime, Time time) {
    if (time.tv_nsec < oldTime.tv_nsec)
        return (Time){
            tv_sec: time.tv_sec - 1 - oldTime.tv_sec,
            tv_nsec: 1E9 + time.tv_nsec - oldTime.tv_nsec
        };
    else
        return (Time){
            tv_sec: time.tv_sec - oldTime.tv_sec,
            tv_nsec: time.tv_nsec - oldTime.tv_nsec
        };
}
static __always_inline __constant double timeSeconds(Time time) {
    return time.tv_sec + time.tv_nsec/1E9;
}
static inline double timeSince(Time oldTime) {
    struct timespec time;
    clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &time);
    return timeSeconds(timeDiff(oldTime, time));
}
```

Answer (score 11):

I can see nothing wrong, but I think it is not optimal.  My compiler warns me
about floating point conversions of those '1E9' constants.  If I rewrite your
`timeAdd` as follows, the code is easier to read and the generated code is
significantly smaller:

```
#define BILLION 1000000000
Time timeAdd(Time t1, Time t2)
{
    long sec = t2.tv_sec + t1.tv_sec;
    long nsec = t2.tv_nsec + t1.tv_nsec;
    if (nsec >= BILLION) {
        nsec -= BILLION;
        sec++;
    }
    return (Time){ .tv_sec = sec, .tv_nsec = nsec };
}
```

The same goes for the other functions, I think.

Comment: If you're using integer BILLION then the timeSeconds expression should include a cast to double, i.e. `time.tv_sec + (double)time.tv_nsec/BILLION;`

Comment: I haven't seen you answer any questions in a while.  I sure hope we haven't seen the last of William Morris.

Comment: @syb0rg not intentionally, but I only really review C and there are some great reviewers (yourself included) who seem always to beat me to it recently :-)

Comment: @WilliamMorris That's usually because I hang out in our [chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/8595/the-2nd-monitor), and there is a constantly updating feed of new questions so I can see when they are posted. :P

Answer (score 3):

Just be careful with your `double timeSeconds(Time time)` function, since a double does not have enough bits to fully express a large number of seconds and a small number of fractional seconds. For example, using a timestamp in the year of 2014, resolution for fractions of a second starts breaking down somewhere around 10us.

Answer (score 1):

You may also want an implementation for `timeCmp` in order to complete your library:

```
// Return 1 if a > b, -1 if a < b, 0 if a == b
static inline __constant int timeCmp(Time a, Time b) {
    if (a.tv_sec != b.tv_sec) {
        if (a.tv_sec > b.tv_sec)
            return 1;
        else 
            return -1;
    } else {
        if (a.tv_nsec > b.tv_nsec)
            return 1;
        else if (a.tv_nsec < b.tv_nsec)
            return -1;
        else
            return 0;
    }
}
```